# X and Y in label.place(x= , Y= ) are co-ordinates of which part of the label specifically as in top-left corner OR bottom-right corner etc..?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I tried to form a drag & drop widget and I can't understand what should I use as the coordinates in the function " drag_motion "(in the code given below), but kindly first answer what does the x and Y are in the label.place(x= , y= ) stand for which location on the widget specifically or do they vary?

```
from tkinter import*

def drag_start(event):
    label.startX = event.x
    label.startY = event.y

def drag_motion(event):
    x = event.x - label.startX
    y = event.y - label.startY 
    label.place(x=x, y=y)


window = Tk()

label = Label(window, bg="red", width=5, height=5)
label.place(x=0, y=0)

label.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
label.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `x` to `x = event.widget.winfo_x() + event.x - label.startX`, similarly for `y` also

Answer (score 0):

`place` gives you an option to control that. From the official documentation (I've modified to reflect python syntax):

> **anchor**=*where* -
> *Where* specifies which point of window is to be positioned at the (x,y) location selected by the **x**, **strong text**y, **relx**, and **rely** options. The anchor point is in terms of the outer area of window including its border, if any. Thus if where is **se** then the lower-right corner of window's border will appear at the given (x,y) location in the container. The anchor position defaults to **nw**.